# Delete duplicate filenames from filesystem

Tags: windows, windows-8, command-line, file-management

How would I write a simple script to remove files with the same name and/or md5 checksum from a target filesystem? I'm sure in a Unix like system this is simple but I'm actually trying to get one going for Windows and I have no idea how Windows works! Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is usually called a "duplicate file finder", but usually nobody cares about identical file names, just content. What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: My question had nothing to do with existing duplicate finding software for windows. But you just go ahead and de-moderate... My question still hasn't been answered.

Comment: This question was closed by five community members who all thought this question was identical to the other one. It might help if you explained what it is you're trying to achieve (and in what way your problem is different from the linked topic). Please also note that questions about programming beyond simple scripting tasks are off topic on this site, so if this is more about writing software than solving the folder comparison problem, you should ask this question elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

Check these out:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Eliminate-duplicate-files (it would not allow me to link here so copy & paste

Here are several free utilities and they all have their advantages and methods.

Auslogics Duplicate File Finder has the MD5 search engine which allows you to find duplicate files by content, regardless other match criteria. It would be helpful, for example, when two identical mp3 tracks or video files have different names
http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/duplicate-file-finder

find and remove duplicate files - free
http://www.easyduplicatefinder.com/
Installer and Portable versions

searches for duplicate or similar files - even binary - free
http://www.joerg-rosenthal.com/en/antitwin/

find fast all duplicate files in a folder and its sub folders - free
http://www.mindgems.com/products/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder-About.htm

Duplicate File Finder - Smart Port Forwarding - TCP Port Scanner - TCP Port Tunnel - Multi-Timer - free
http://www.brooksyounce.com/

Duplicate File Finder Software (images, mp3, iTunes)
http://www.moleskinsoft.com/